# Is Opera on mobile iOS8 using WKWebView or UIWebView?

Tags: mobile, ios8, opera, wkwebview

After exhaustive search on Google I can't confirm whether they have upgraded Opera to use WKWebView or not?
Can anyone provide a link confirming it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is simple trick to determine it.
Previous to iOS8 every phone browser used UIWebView, UIWebView doesn't support `indexedDB` inherently. So a simple check for `indexedDB` will solve the need to check for WKWebView.

Code for test :

```
if (window.indexedDB === undefined) {
    console.log('UIWebView still in use');
} else {
    console.log('Browser has switched to WKWebView. Hurray!!');
}
```

One can go for other attribute also. I just described one possible way.

Cheers